# cursor.description "type_code" correspondence with database field types

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection

Using a MySQL back-end and basically want to determine the field type of tables from the type_code in the cursor.description tuples...

What I get is a bunch of different numbers... and by comparing my tables with the type_code values I can manually put together a set of correspondences... but I have many more types than the type objects documented in my Python book (Beazley), namely STRING, BINARY, NUMBER, DATETIME, ROWID.

I presume there are therefore different type_codes being given to things like DECIMAL, UNSIGNED INT, etc... but I'm just surprised not to be able to find any info out here or on the Net generally.

What I want to do, by the way, is to automate the process whereby input (in a GUI grid connected to a MySQL table for example) determines what type of data the table is expecting for that column, and parses and checks it to find out whether this is a legal value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic type codes as described in your book are defined by the [DB-API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

> The type_code must compare equal to one of Type Objects defined below.

The trick here is that there can be multiple different type codes that all compare equal to the same type object.

```
>>> MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.TIMESTAMP
7
>>> MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME
12
>>> MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.TIMESTAMP==MySQLdb.DATETIME
True
>>> MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME==MySQLdb.DATETIME
True
>>> MySQLdb.DATETIME
DBAPISet([12, 7])
```

(How this magic is implemented is outlined in the note about DBAPITypeObject in the DB-API spec. A more conventional interface might have done this with subclasses...)

This allows MySQLdb to offer richer information about the column than just whether it's a date-and-time type, whilst still allowing a simple test for a string vs a number.

Of course if you start comparing against MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE types directly you are relying on MySQLdb functionality that won't port to other databases.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in getting a dictionary of how ids map to descriptions:

```
>>> ft = MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE
>>> d = {getattr(ft, k): k for k in dir(ft) if not k.startswith('_')}
>>> d
{0: 'DECIMAL',
 1: 'TINY',
 2: 'SHORT',
 3: 'LONG',
 4: 'FLOAT',
 5: 'DOUBLE',
 6: 'NULL',
 7: 'TIMESTAMP',
 8: 'LONGLONG',
 9: 'INT24',
 10: 'DATE',
 11: 'TIME',
 12: 'DATETIME',
 13: 'YEAR',
 14: 'NEWDATE',
 15: 'VARCHAR',
 16: 'BIT',
 246: 'NEWDECIMAL',
 247: 'INTERVAL',
 248: 'SET',
 249: 'TINY_BLOB',
 250: 'MEDIUM_BLOB',
 251: 'LONG_BLOB',
 252: 'BLOB',
 253: 'VAR_STRING',
 254: 'STRING',
 255: 'GEOMETRY'}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `MySQLdb`, then the `MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE` module contains constants for each field type.

```
>>> print dir(MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE)
['BIT', 'BLOB', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'DOUBLE', 'ENUM', 
 'FLOAT', 'GEOMETRY', 'INT24', 'INTERVAL', 'LONG', 'LONGLONG', 'LONG_BLOB', 
 'MEDIUM_BLOB', 'NEWDATE', 'NEWDECIMAL', 'NULL', 'SET', 'SHORT', 'STRING', 
 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'TINY', 'TINY_BLOB', 'VARCHAR', 'VAR_STRING', 'YEAR',
 '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

For example, the a typecode of `5` indicates it is a MySQL double

```
>>> MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.DOUBLE 
5
```

This module is noted in the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

Comment: thanks... you see, I had never heard of MySQLdb... just Googled it - I hope everything will fall into place...